# Converting two arraylist to a 2D string

Tags: java, arraylist

While developing an application i come across a situation as below:

I have two Arralylists - list1, list2 which have values like:

```
list1 = [district1, district2, district3, district4, district5]
list2 = [service1, service2, service3, sevice4, service5]
```

Now i want to store the values in a third arraylist, list3 which will be like:

```
list3 = [district1, service1, district2, service2, district3, service3, district4, service4, district5, service 5]
```

Now i need to convert list3 to a two dimensional String (values[][]) which will be like:

```
values = [ [district1, service1], [district2, service2], [district3, service3], [district4, service4], [district5, service 5]]
```

Basically i need values[][]. I am not sure whether list3 is required or not. I spend the whole day working on this, bt couldnot figure out a solution. Would really appreciate someone's help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not required ... declare a `String[][]` of length `list1.size()` Iterate through both the `List` and populate the `String[][]`.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot That's up to OP's case whether or not this is required...

Comment: @Aquillo OP says ***Basically i need values[][]**. I am not sure whether list3 is required or not.*

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Ok, in case OP is talking about objects with `values[][]` that's true. Though OP has not specified whether he needs objects or a single string. A single string could be required based on his requirement (e.g. for writing to textfiles).

Comment: Use `HashMap` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lists contain `String` and `list1.size() == list2.size()`:

```
String[][] values = new String[list1.size()][2];
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    values[0] = list1.get(i);
    values[1] = list2.get(i);
}
```

Comment: That's what I said, but I edited the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, but my lists contain objects and not String. i tried using the following:

Comment: Okay, then replace `String` with `Object` or whatever class you are using.

Comment: I tried using the following

String[][] values = new String[list1.size()][2];
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    values[0] = (String)list1.get(i);
    values[1] = (String)list2.get(i);
}
but when i see the console using sysout its showing
Values: [[Ljava.lang.String;@17f84da

Comment: I suppose `list1` and `list2` don't contain `String`, but some objects. Declare the array to hold the same type as the lists and delete the `String` cast.

Answer (score 0):

If list1 and list2 have same # of elements then something like following code should work for you:

```
String[][] list3 = new String[list1.size()][2];

for (int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++) {
   list3[i][0] = list1.get(i);
   list3[i][1] = list2.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both the lists are of same size, following code would help:

```
public String[][] merge(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        String[][] values = new String[list1.size()][];

        for(int i=0 ; i< list1.size() ; i++){
            values[i] = new String[2];
            values[i][0] = list1.get(i);
            values[i][1] = list2.get(i);
        }
        return values;
    }
```